# Issues with code in dynamically created fragments

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm building an app with multiple pages to it, each of the main pages is displayed in a fragment in the main activity. Whenever the user wants to change page, the fragment within the activity is changed.

I want to write the code for each fragment within its own java file, as opposed to writing the code for all of the fragments within the main activity.

I've tried putting each bit of code within the fragment's onCreate and onCreateView methods (including trying onStart, onPause and whole other load of ones) but I've noticed that when the fragment is created the code just isn't running.

I've seen other questions on here with similar issues but none of the answers offered me an actual solution.

My question is this, how can I write the code for each fragment within that fragment's java file and actually get it to run? I understand this would be much easier if my fragments were created statically in the activity but these are not, they are created at runtime.

For reference, each fragment is displayed in the activity like so:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, HomeFragment.newInstance(position)).commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
From main activity you can call a **static method** defined in your fragment class as:

```
AuthFragment.NewInstance(LoginActivity.this, constantsObj);
```

This only line will go in your fragment calling activity.

Now in your fragment, inside the **static method**, find and create the fragment as,

```
 public static void NewInstance(LoginActivity activityContext, Constants constantsObj) {
    clsConstantsObj = constantsObj;
    urlToCatch = clsConstantsObj.toString();
    urlToCatch = urlToCatch.replace("/params", "");

    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    activityContextInFragment = activityContext;

    fragmentManager = activityContext.getSupportFragmentManager();

    AuthFragment findAuthFragment = (AuthFragment) fragmentManager
            .findFragmentByTag("authFragment");

    if (findAuthFragment == null) {
        AuthFragment authFragment = new AuthFragment();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainviewRegionwise, authFragment, "authFragment");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Notice the "R.id.mainviewRegionwise", which is the id of your main container which could be a FrameLayout or any other container.

Comment: In this context what is authFragment? Is that a placeholder fragment or the fragment I am creating this method in? And just to clarify, is the second block of code going in that of the fragment that I am attempting to open?

Comment: 1. In this context what is authFragment? Is that a placeholder fragment or the fragment I am creating this method in?
--->
AuthFragment is the fragment that you are trying to create dynamically.
and the code will go in calling activity or fragment....
2.And just to clarify, is the second block of code going in that of the fragment that I am attempting to open?
--->>
Yes, you are right, the second block will go in your dynamic fragment class

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I realised yesterday that I had actually made a much bigger mistake which I've now fixed but this helped me to neaten things up a bit. Thanks a lot.